# Why does `-` parameter order cause Racket REPL to run out of memory?

Tags: scheme, racket

I'm seeing an issue when swapping the order of parameters to the `-` function.

```
; source

(define (compose f g) (lambda (x) (f (g x))))

(define (repeated f n)
  (if (= n 1)
    f
    (compose f (repeated f (- 1 n))) ; causes an out of memory error
    (compose f (repeated f (- n 1))) ; runs without issue
))

(define (square n) (* n n))
((repeated square 2) 6) ; 1296


; REPL

> > Racket virtual machine has run out of memory; aborting
Aborted (core dumped)
```

The problem stands if I hardcode the value. Also, the problem doesn't apply if I increment `n` using `+`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you start with `n` being `2`, you then call `(repeated f (- 1 2))`. `(- 1 2)` is `-1`, which is not equal to `1`, so it continues with `(repeated f (- 1 -1))`. `(- 1 -1)` is 2, so you call `(repeated f 2)` again and you have reached an infinite loop.

When using the other order you start with `(- 2 1)`, which is `1`, so that's where the recursion stops.

In other words: if you start with a number greater than `1` and you keep subtracting `1` from `n`, you'll eventually reach `1` and the recursion will stop. If you instead subtract `n` from `1`, you'll get into a cycle and the recursion will continue forever (or rather until you run out of memory).

The same problem doesn't occur with addition because addition is commutative. That is adding `x` to `y` and adding `y` to `x` produce the exact same result. The same is not true for subtraction.